# .htaccess & .htpasswd not accepting login data

Tags: .htaccess, .htpasswd

I'm trying to password protect my website: http://www.massmindmanipulation.com

I've created a .htacces & a .htpasswd file, and the login box pops up when I visit the website.

But when I enter the login information, the box quickly disappears and reappears.  Nothing else happens.

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
AuthName "Members Only"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/mass/public_html/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
require valid-user
```

And here is my .htpasswd file:

```
1:2
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an `index.html` file that Apache can look for? If not, try making one, put in something simple and then try again.